# Почему выполняется метод toString() в классе Human, но не выполняется speak()?

Tags: java, объекты

Взял код с JavaRush.
Интересно, почему при создании объекта класса `Human` автоматически срабатывает `toString()`, а мой метод `speak()` — нет?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = String.valueOf(1);
        String b = String.valueOf(12.0D);
        String c = String.valueOf(123.4F);
        String d = String.valueOf(123456L);
        String s = String.valueOf(true);
        Human alex = new Human("Alex");
        String human = String.valueOf(alex);

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(d);
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(human);
        /*
        Вывод:
        1
        12.0
        123.4
        123456
        true
        Человек с именем Alex
         */
    }

    static class Human {
        private String name;

        public Human(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Человек с именем " + name;
        }
        
        public void speak(){
            System.out.println("asdk;asd");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `speak` не срабатывает просто потому, что нигде не вызывается

Comment: *"при создании объекта класса Human автоматически срабатывает toString"* - это не так. `toString` срабатывает позже, в строке `String human = String.valueOf(alex);`.  Используя метод `.valueOf(alex)`, вы неявно вызываете `toString()`  - [см. пояснение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27465774/15035314).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. ВАШ метод не сработает, пока ВЫ его явно не вызовете. Иначе бы при исполнении кода происходил бы кавардак и методы срабатывали бы, когда не надо. Поэтому если вы хотите, чтобы метод сработал, вызовете его:

```java
alex.speak();
```

2. Теперь про `toString()`. Он вызывается, когда нужно объект представить в виде строки. Например, вы выводите объект на экран. В вашем случае он вызывается в этой строке:

```
String human = String.valueOf(alex);
```

Ведь вы с помощью метода [`String.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-) хотите представить объект в виде строки. Поэтому `valueOf()` дёргает `toString()`  в классе `Human`.

Важно заметить, что `toString()` - особый метод, это один из методов класса [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), от которого наследуются все классы в языке java. Поэтому иногда его вызывают методы из стандартных java-библиотек. А о вашем методе `speak()` стандартные java-библиотеки ничего не знают. Потому что это ВАШ метод, а не переопределение метода из класса `Object`.

Ну и при создании объекта класса `toString()` конечно же НЕ вызывается. Потому что ЗАЧЕМ? ЗАЧЕМ *при создании объекта* получать его строковое представление? Совершенно незачем.

Comment: Анонимного минусатора прошу комментировать минусы. Особенно пачки минусов.